# django queryset not showing accurate result (building a news app)

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-templates, django-queryset

I am creating a news app using django. It consists of search by date option. When i choose the date(ex:29-11-2020) and click submit, It should take me to the news of that particular day. When i try the below code instead of showing the details it is giving me a blank page.
views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.views.generic import ListView

def index(request):
    return render(request,'newspaperapp/index.html')

class nowlist(ListView):
     model = newsmodel_1
     template_name = 'newspaperapp/index.html'

class newslist(DetailView):
    model = newsmodel_1
    template_name = 'newspaperapp/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'newspaperapp'

# search by giving date in index and search date
class SearchView(ListView):
     model = newsmodel_1
     template_name = 'newspaperapp/search.html'
     context_object_name = 'all_search_results'

def get_queryset(self):
    result = super(SearchView, self).get_queryset()
    query = self.request.GET.get('search')
    if query:
         postresult = newsmodel_1.objects.filter(date_published__contains=query)
             result = postresult
        else:
            result = None
        return result
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
app_name = 'newspaperapp'
from .views import newslist,SearchView,nowlist
from newspaperapp import views
urlpatterns = [
     path('',views.index,name='index'),
     path('date/',nowlist.as_view(),name = "date"),
     path('<int:pk>',newslist.as_view(),name = "home"),
     path('results/', SearchView.as_view(), name='search'),
     ]
```

newspaperapp/home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Today's Paper</p>
    {{newspaperapp.date_published}}
    {{newspaperapp.category}}
 </body>
```

newspaperapp/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <!-- this page has search option and different categories of news -->
 <!-- to create search option we write views code and continue -->
 <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" method="GET" action="{% url 'newspaperapp:search' %}">
 <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="date" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" 
  name="search">
 <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
 </form>

{%for newspaperapp in object_list %}
<li><a href="{%url 'newspaperapp:home' newspaperapp.pk %}">{{newspaperapp.title}}</a>
 {{newspaperapp.date_published}}
 {%endfor%}
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

newspaperapp/search.html

```
{% block content %}
{% for newspaperapp in all_search_results %}
    <h3><a href="{%url 'newspaperapp:home' newspaperapp.pk %}"></a></h3>
{% empty %}
    <h2>No results found</h2>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Your input does not have name="search" attribute so it is not sent and it results in your result being None ( check your if condition)

Answer (score 1):

`Contain` usually translated to `LIKE` in sql typically is used to search for a specified **text pattern** in a column.

If you want to filter date, you could convert `query` it to datetime object, and search the objects in that particular date range using **[`gte`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gte)** and **[`lt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#lt)** lookups.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class SearchView(ListView):
    model = newsmodel_1
    template_name = 'newspaperapp/search.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_search_results'

    def get_queryset(self):
        result = super(SearchView, self).get_queryset()
        query = self.request.GET.get('search')
        # query is of type 'str', convert to datetime
        start_day = datetime.fromisoformat(query)
        end_day   = start_day + timedelta(days=1)
        if query:
             postresult = newsmodel_1.objects.filter(
                 date_published__gte=start_day, 
                 date_published__lt=end_day
             )
             result = postresult
        else:
            result = None
        return result
```

Note: add more logic to handle `query` is `None`

Comment: still the same result.

Comment: @PadalaKavya  forget the item in `<a>` tag? `<h3><a href="{%url 'newspaperapp:home' newspaperapp.pk %}">{{ newspaperapp }}</a></h3>`, try also to print the `postresult` to see if the queryset is passed correctly

Comment: I actually want to go directly to the details page after clicking on search but the above code is taking me to the link of the detail page. How do i solve this issue?? please help